# cassandra create column family error

Tags: cassandra

I'm starting to learn cassandra. So far I have created a keyspace. Next, I simply want to create a column family. Reading docs, this should simply be:

```
create column family DATASTORE;
```

I keep getting the error:

```
Bad Request: line 1:7 no viable alternative at input 'column'
```

Installed Cassandra on windows.
I'm using Cassandra CQL. 
Thanks.

Comment: I voted to close, this is the first thing you find if you search for "create a table with cql".

Comment: if i wanted to create a table, yes that would be. But as per question, its a column family i want to create.

Comment: They are the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest reading the ["Creating a table with CQL" section of the docs](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/1.2/index.html#cassandra/cql_using/create_table_t.html).

Comment: thanks theo, as per above, its not a table i wish to create, but a column family..

Answer (score 1):

This command is only appropriate for the CLI Utility application - and is not valid CQL. This video provides a good overview: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WSCrwBueoPI&list=PL3E5AC388940EEC0A

Answer (score 1):

You need to supply more parameters to dictate what the table (also known as a column family) will store.

First create a keyspace (the below is in cql)

```
CREATE KEYSPACE firstkeyspace 
WITH REPLICATION = 
{
 'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 
 'replication_factor': '2'
}
```

Then here is what you want. This will create a table named `userz` in the `firstkeyspace` keyspace. The below table will store two columns (columns as in columns of a table).

```
CREATE TABLE firstkeyspace.userz (
 user text,
 password text,
 PRIMARY KEY (user)
);
```